# Can anybody debug this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, database, innodb

## SQL QUERY

```
$sql = "  INSERT INTO foldertable(`serverToken` , `folderName` , `folderid` , `folderPath` , `createdTime` , `LastEdited` , `previewPath` , `userFolderPathName`)
                     SELECT (SELECT serverToken FROM `servertoken` WHERE `userToken` = ? LIMIT 1) ,? ,? ,? ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ,? ,?
                     FROM foldertable
                     WHERE (`folderPath` = ?
                     AND serverToken = (SELECT serverToken FROM `servertoken` WHERE `userToken` = ? LIMIT 1))
```

The `$sql` is working fine. but the problem is in `mysqli_stmt_execute` returning `true` when `folderPath` is not matched but returning `false` when `userToken` not found in `servertoken` database.

I am unable to understand this behavior. I will be grateful if you can explain this.

I think given info is enough to debug this, if not tell me.

Comment: If `userToken` is not found, the insert query will fail. Your columns might not be supporting NULL values

Comment: You could add `servertoken` table as inner join so you dont need the second where statement

Comment: You can also cache `SELECT serverToken FROM servertoken WHERE userToken = ? LIMIT 1` in  a variable in the query.

Comment: Please share more details. What's the exact question? Why `mysqli_stmt_execute` returns either `true` or `false`?

Comment: Suggest reformulating the query to have the `( SELECT serverToken ... ) as a 'derived' table, thereby needing to state it only once.